# How to display a table from java servlet into my react js application using axios?

Tags: java, reactjs, servlets, axios

I am trying to deploy this table in my react app whose code has been provided in the material UI itself. The table is-
https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting

The thing is that I am trying to fetch the data for the table from my java servlet using axios. For fetching the data from the servlet, what I have so far is:

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('link of my servlet')

.then( (response) => {
    this.setState({response: response})
})
.catch( (error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
}
```

Now I have fetched the data from sql to my servlet in the form of a table. What I don't understand is how do I to fetch the table values that are being displayed in the servlet to the table I have in react.

Any tiny help will be great. Thank you in advance!